# How can I rerender only one item in a flatlist?

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I have products with a star icon to add this product in wishlist. I map 10 list of products and each map has 3 products like:

(I Map it in Pagerview to swipe to the next products)

Products Component

```
const ListProducts = [
  {
    id: 1,
    products: [{
      product_id: 1,
      photos: [...]
    }]
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    products: [{
      product_id: 1,
      photos: [...]
    }]
  }
  {
    id: 3,
    products: [{
      product_id: 1,
      photos: [...]
    }]
  },
  {
    id: 4,
    products: [{
      product_id: 1,
      photos: [...]
    }]
  }
...
];


function isEq(prev, next) {
  if(prev.is_wishlist === next.is_wishlist) {
    return true;
  }
}

const Item = memo(({ id, photos, is_wishlist, onPress, onPressWishlist }) => {
  const findProductIdInWishList = is_wishlist.find((el => el.product_id === id));
  return (
    <Button style={s.imgBtn} onPress={() => onPress(id)}>
      <Button onPress={() => onPressWishlist(id)} style={s.starBtn}>
        <AntDesign name={findProductIdInWishList ? 'star' : 'staro'} size={20} color={globalStyles.globalColor} />
      </Button>
      <ImageSlider photos={photos} />
    </Button>
  )
  // @ts-ignore
}, isEq);

  const wishlist = useSelector((state) => state.WishList.wishlist);
  const dispatch = useDispatch();

  const renderItem: ListRenderItem<IProduct> = ({ item }) => (
    <Item
      id={item.id}
      photos={item.photos}
      is_wishlist={wishlist}
      onPressWishlist={handlePressWishList}
    />
  )


  const handlePressWishList = (product_id: string) => {
    dispatch(addAndRemoveProductToWishList({product_id}));
  };
```

List of Products component

```
Products Map:

      <PagerView onPageSelected={(e) => handleSetAllIndexes(e.nativeEvent.position)} style={s.container} initialPage={index}>
      {
        allProducts.map((el, i) => (
          <View style={s.viewsContainer} key={i}>
            { allIndex.includes(i) ? (
              <View style={s.viewsInnerContainer}>
                { /* products */ }
                <Products products={el.products as IProduct[]} total_price={el.total_price} product_name={el.packet_name} />
              </View>
              ) : (
              <View style={s.loadingContainer}>
                <Loader size={'large'} color='#fff' />
              </View>
              )
            }
          </View>)
        )
      }
      </PagerView>
```

if I click on star icon its dispatch and it goes fast but if I swipe to other products maybe to the last, then I press the star icon to dispatch then its a delay/lag you can see it

I dont add the full code because there are some snippets that has nothing to do with problem.

PS:

[Video](https://files.fm/u/97q9mrevh#/view/ruydc6ak7)

Comment: Did you try to remove the condition 'allIndex.includes(i)'? The loading indicator shows because of that.

Comment: @Four my fault I dont have explain detailed, I mean if I swipe to the last product and then clicking the star icon its lag, I get a delay if I press the star icon, look at the end of video

Answer (score 1):

I am going to edit my answer instead of comment. Before my code, let me explain first. In your current code, whenever 'allProducts' changes, everything will re-render. Whenever 'allIndex' changes, everything will re-render too. The longer the list, the more lag it will be. 
Can you try 'useCallback' in this case?

```
const renderItem = React.useCallback((el, i) => (
  <View style={s.viewsContainer} key={i}>
      {allIndex.includes(i) ? (
        <View style={s.viewsInnerContainer}>
          <Products />
        </View>
      ) : (
        <Loading />
      )}
    </View>
),[allIndex])

{allProducts.map(renderItem)}
```

Now, renderItem will re-render when 'allIndex' changes. Instead of 'PagerView', I still recommend 'FlatList' with 'horizontal={true}' and 'some styles'. If still wanna use 'PagerView', how about 'Lazy' components? 'Lazy components' does not render the components before they came into user view. So, before they are seen, they do not take part in re-redner.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer, If I dispatch It does not show the ohter icon when the item is in wishlist, so I add is_wishlist in useMemo dependencies, but the laag with 1-2seconds is still there look at the video: https://www.veed.io/view/140548e5-80d0-4d3f-bb68-2d2980bfd9da

Comment: I did not consider that problem before. Now I look, I saw you are mapping 'Array/object' with 'FlatList'. You have this data structure '{
    id: 1,
    products: [{
      product_id: 1,
      photos: [...]
    }]
  }'. Why are products 'Array' here? If you want to group your products, can you  try with 'SectionList' instead of 'FlatList'?

Comment: Because every person have products and I want to show all persons products when I swipe to right then there is another persons products and so on, therefore I use products in array :D, I look at sectionList, never used before

Answer (score 1):

I think there are a few issues in your code:

##### 1. Wrong dependency list for `useMemo`.

In your `Item` component, you should pass the list of dependency, rather than a compare function:

```js
const Item = memo(({ id, photos, is_wishlist, onPress, onPressWishlist }) => {
  ...
  // @ts-ignore
}, isEq);  // <- this is wrong

// Instead, you should do this:
}, [is_wishlist]);  // <- this is correct, if you only want to update Item component when `is_wishlist` is changed
```

##### 2. Never use index as key if item can be reordered

In your products maps component, you are doing:

```js
allProducts.map((el, i) => (
  <View style={s.viewsContainer} key={i}>
```

You should pass id instead, so React will not re-render all items when you insert a new item at the beginning or in the middle:

```
<View style={s.viewsContainer} key={el.id}>
```

##### 3. Passing `wishlist` to all Items, however, `wishlist` will be updated whenever user click star button on any item.

This causes all Item to re-generate memoized component, because `wishlist` is changed.

What you want to do here is only passing essential data to `Item`, which is `inWishList` (or `findProductIdInWishList` in your code), which only get changed for affected item:

```
const renderItem: ListRenderItem<IProduct> = ({ item }) => {
  const inWishList= wishlist.find((el => el.product_id === id));
  return (
    <Item
      id={item.id}
      photos={item.photos}
      inWishList={inWishList}
      onPressWishlist={handlePressWishList}
    />
  )
}
```

Comment: thank for your answer, I followed your steps, but in the first step I dont use useMemo, i use only memo func, so I dont have put any dependencies in their or I am wrong ?

Comment: Have you tried #2-#3? I don't think it is really necessary to memo the component here

Comment: yes but its not working I get still the delay, Do you want the full code in editor or can you watch it with teamviewer

Comment: You can create a minimal reprod in https://codesandbox.io/embed/q4qymyp2l6 and save and share the link here

Answer (score 0):

The issue is connected to a way how you edit your data to hold the new value. It looks like the act of adding an item to a wishlist causes all the previous items to re-render.
Therefore the first one works without an issue, but the last one takes a while as it needs to re-render all the other items before.
I would start by changing the key from index to an actual ID of a product block since that could prevent the other "pages" from re-rendering.

If that fails you will probably need to take this block of code into a workshop and check for useless re-renders.